# How do i remove the degree symbol (°) from an integer

Tags: python

I am making a program with python to go get weather data (forecast and daily) and store it in an Excel sheet. The program is also getting the ° sign, excel keeps denying it and causing errors. I'm using this DailyTemp.remove('u\N{DEGREE SIGN}') to remove the degree sign but it's looking for '°' instead of the symbol itself.

I was wondering how to either pull the tic marks out or search for the symbol by itself.

Comment: in unicode string you can put the symbol directly in the remove statement

Comment: What is the literal text that you receive? What is your code?

Answer (score 2):

There is probably more elegant solution but this should work.

```
a = '29°'
print(a.strip('°'))
```

Also if you want to convert this to an integer you can do this by:

```
int(a)
```

Comment: Looks like you're shy one bracket.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Talip Tolga Sari's answer, you could use slicing (assuming you're working with a string).

```
a = '29°'
print(a[:len(a)-1])

Output: 
'29'
```

You could also replace the degree symbol with a space via the `replace` string method.

```
a = '29°'
b = a.replace('°', '')
print(b)  

Output: 
'29'
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log("123° asdf 12331° aaaa 321°".replace(/(\d+)°/g, (_, num) => num));
```